# How to fix this error (querySelector is used): Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'style') at showSlides

Tags: javascript, html

I am unable to resolve this error; I've been "fighting" to solve it for two days.

This is the error:

*215: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'style') at showSlides*

[image]

```js
var slideIndex = 1;


    var outerXmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = "https://wjko8t4509.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/books";
    outerXmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
      var innerXmlhttp;
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        var allbook = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        for (var i = 0, len = allbook.Items.length; i < len; i++) {
          id = allbook.Items[i].id
          document.querySelector('.slideshow-container').innerHTML += `
          <div class="mySlides fade">
            <div class="numbertext">${i+1}/${allbook.Items.length}</div>
            <img id="img" src onerror="this.onerror=null; this.src=myFunction(id);" style="width:100%">
            <div class="text" id="title" onclick="myFunction(id)"></div>
          </div>`;
          document.querySelector('#punt').innerHTML += `
          <span class="dot" onclick=currentSlide(${i+1})></span>`;
          myFunction(id);
        }
      }
    };
    outerXmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
    outerXmlhttp.send();

    showSlides(slideIndex);

    function plusSlides(n) {
      showSlides(slideIndex += n);
    }

    function currentSlide(n) {
      showSlides(slideIndex = n);
    }

    function showSlides(n) {
      var i;
      var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides fade");
      var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
      if (n > slides.length) { slideIndex = 1 }
      if (n < 1) { slideIndex = slides.length }
      for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
        slides[i].style.display = "none";
      }
      for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
        dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
      }
      slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
      dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
    }

    function myFunction(id) {
      var url1 = "https://wjko8t4509.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/books/" + id;
      innerXmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      innerXmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
          var myArr = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
          document.getElementById("img").src = "book_img/" + myArr.Item.immagine;
          document.getElementById("title").innerHTML = `<a href="fragmentProva.html?id=${id}">${myArr.Item.titolo}</a>`;
        }
      };
      innerXmlhttp.open("GET", url1, true);
      innerXmlhttp.send();
    }
```

```html
<div class="slideshow-container" id="slideshow">
    <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
    <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
  </div>

  <br>

  <div id="punt" style="text-align:center">
  </div>
```

I would not like there to be some setup problem regarding the querySelector or the function call. I need your help, help me please!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`showSlides` runs before the `mySlides` container is populated from `outerXmlhttp`

try calling `showSlides` from `outerXmlhttp`

```
showSlides(slideIndex);
myFunction(id);
```

Comment: Perfect, that was the problem. Thank you